# Probability of a certain final score in soccer when you know each of the two teams' probabilities to score a certain number of goals

Tags: probability, distributions, joint-distribution, dependent-variable

Let's suppose that you have data from about $2000$ soccer matches from a certain league. Your data shows that the home team's probability of scoring $0$ goals is $0.245263157894737$. The away team's probability of scoring $0$ goals is $0.321052631578947$. Now, if you just multiply the two probabilities you find that the probabilities for a $0-0$ score (i.e. both teams scoring $0$ goals) is $0.0787423822714681$. But, the actual data shows that the probability of this scenario is only $0.0668421052631579$, or, in other words, that the result will be $0-0$ in $6.69\%$ of the total games.

The only way to explain this difference is to assume that the probabilities of both teams scoring $0$ goals are dependent on each other, so you can't just multiply the individual teams' probabilities. My question is: what would be the proper way of combining dependent probabilities or dependent probability distributions in such a case? I'm not a statistician or a mathematician, just a hobbyist, and most of the answers I have found on the net are either two complicated for my level of knowledge in stats or simply don't work (supposing I have understood them correctly). Could someone please provide an answer as detailed as possible for the procedure I should follow? Please note that I have no knowledge of R or such packages and I can only use LibreOffice Calc or Microsoft Excel for computations.

Comment: Sorry, but I think you have imposed impossible conditions. You want a simple solution to a complex problem and you insist on using inadequate tools.